# What algorithm is used here?

Tags: opencv, ocr

This is simple text detection video made using an opencv.
Any ideas how was that made?

[Opencv video 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLG28-xNoMU)

[Opencv video 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57uOKBnJ4Mo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author describes what he's doing in the comments to the video you linked.

> I basically look for dark pixels
>   aligned horizontally, put a box around
>   them and call them letters.

He also mentions

> If you like i could share the source code.

...so if you're still curious, you know what to do.

Comment: IF YOU understand how to search for dark pixels aligned horizontally, then please explain me

Comment: I would... search for dark pixels aligned horizontally.  More precisely, search for pixels within a certain brightness distance from black, at aligned within, say, 80% from horizontal.  If you want more detail, ask the poster.  It's his algorithm, we'd just be guessing.

Comment: You can use the hough transform to detect lines. http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/feature_detection.html#houghlines2